# Why am I getting an "auth failed" error when connecting to MongoDB with correct credentials?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am getting an "auth failed" error when running my server connecting to MongoDB. I am using the correct credentials:

```
> db.createUser( { user: "admin2", pwd:"Testabcd", roles: [ "dbAdmin" ]} )
```

> Successfully added user: { "user" : "admin2", "roles" : [ "dbAdmin" ] }

```
var MONGO = {
    username: "admin2",
    password: "Testabcd",
    server: '127.0.0.1',
    port: '27017',
    db: 'test',
    connectionString: function(){return 'mongodb://'+this.username+':'+this.password+'@'+this.server+':'+this.port+'/'+this.db;},
    options: {server:{auto_reconnect: true,socketOptions:{connectTimeoutMS:60000,keepAlive:60000,socketTimeoutMS:60000}}}
};
```

says the following when saving a user to the Mongo database:

> User not saved because of errorMongoError: auth failed

I have got this working multiple times and never had an issue. Now I'm having all sorts of problems.

Comment: In which database do you have created the user `admin2`?

Comment: Is authentication is enabled (it's disabled by default) on your mongod configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**'dbAdmin'** role does not allow you to add user to a DB.
Use **'userAdmin'** instead:

```
db.createUser( { user: "admin2", pwd:"Testabcd", roles: [ "userAdmin" ]} )
```

Alternatively, use **'dbOwner'** role, which is a combination of **'readWrite'**, **'dbAdmin'** and **'userAdmin'** roles

```
db.createUser( { user: "admin2", pwd:"Testabcd", roles: [ "dbOwner" ]} )
```

Ref: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/built-in-roles/